# Citrix Receiver Resolution 4K on MacOS

Tags: macos, citrix

I have a Retina screen MacBook Pro with a 15.6" 4K external monitor attached. I've discovered the resolution of the Citrix session is terrible unless I set the (MacOS) display resolution to `3840x2160`, in which case the session resolution is perfect.

The trouble is at this setting, the resolution outside of the session, in MacOS is tiny - I usually have it set to scaled slightly larger. Without the external screen attached, the situation is the same with the default native display resolution resulting in very poor quality in the session.

Is there any solution where both the Citrix session and MacOS both look good?

Comment: Hmm. Situation is more complicated than I realised. After restarting the remote machine, the resolution was wrong again. Now have it clear again with 3840x2160 local resolution, windows scaling set to 175% and Citrix Receiver High DPI set to yes (inside windows machine)

Answer (score 1):

`defaults write com.citrix.receiver.nomas EnableHighDPI -bool YES`

Answer (score 0):

> I have a Retina screen MacBook Pro with a 15.6" 4K **external monitor attached**.

According to Citrix they don't have a solution yet.

> ## Prerequisites
>
> - To try out on individual MacBooks without enabling for the entire organization/store or if you do not want to whitelist LaunchDarkly on your internal network, you can run the following command in macOS Terminal
>
>   ```
>   defaults write com.citrix.receiver.nomas EnableHighDPI -bool YES
>   ```
>
> ## Limitations
>
> - Supported devices: MacBook, MacBook Pro. Devices not supported: Mac mini, iMacs, Mac Pro.
> - **No Multi monitor support**. This feature will not work if you have connected a secondary monitor. Even if you don't use the secondary monitor with the Citrix Workspace app, simply connecting it will cause this feature to not be available. This feature works only when you use a single monitor for your device.

<sub>Source: https://support.citrix.com/article/CTX270704/citrix-workspace-app-for-macos-and-retina-displays</sub>

I tried it on my M1 Mac. After I disconnected the Thunderbolt dock with all peripherals the running session changed the resolution by itself to higher DPI. As soon as I connected an external monitor I was back to 1080p.